# Temporary table creation in Oracle

Tags: oracle, temp-tables

Is there any way to create a temporary table in Oracle which gets dropped by itself once the schema connection gets closed? Does local temporary table wok similar way?

Comment: There is no `local temporary` table in Oracle. And no, there are no temp tables that are automatically dropped. But why would you need that?

Comment: Thank you for the info! I have been working in Teradata where I had an option Volatile table which gets dropped automatically once the session ends. In case I wanna save the data for a small time and have to drop it once the work is done Volatile tables help a lot.

Comment: In most cases you don't really need a temporary table in Oracle. Using a CTE usually works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution for your problem would be to use GTT's ([Global Temporary Tables](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables)).

They will allow you to store temporary data in them, which will be available per session.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (
  id           NUMBER,
  description  VARCHAR2(20)
)
```

Also, this data can be deleted by specifying a `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;` option at the end of the creation script, like:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (
  id           NUMBER,
  description  VARCHAR2(20)
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

As mentioned on the website:

"The `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` clause indicates that the data should be deleted at the end of the transaction, or the end of the session."

You can also take a look at the [Oracle docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefdeclaretemptable.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can create temp table in oracle once and not every session. However, the rows you insert into it are visible only to your session, and are automatically deleted when you end you session or end of the transaction.